# How to use sync in 3 column pivot table?

Tags: php, laravel

```
Pivot: team_member
team_id  |  member_id  |  status  |
-----------------------------------
   1     |      1      |    1     |
   1     |      2      |    1     |
   2     |      3      |    1     |
   3     |      4      |    1     |
```

How to update the last record to status 0 by using sync function?

```
$team = Team::find(3);
$member_ids = [4];
$status = 0;

$team->members()->sync($member_ids, ['status' => 0]);
```

Sync is not working if the team_id and member_id are same like exisitng one.

**Team Model**

```
   public function members() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Member::class, 'team_member', 'team_id', 'member_id')->withPivot('status');
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't `$member_ids` contain objects, not integers? `$member_ids = [App\User::find(4)]` https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships although it doesn't explicitly state that, it is implied in that they use `$roleId` and `$role` in their examples

Comment: @zanderwar I get "Illegal offset type" after change integer to object by using $member_ids = [Member::find(4)]

Comment: Try a single object, not an array of

Comment: @zanderwar after remove array no more error, but the 'status' field still no update

Comment: Sync would reassign what teams that member belongs too, so it would have unassigned it from any team that wasn't in the list

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

Updating A Record On A Pivot Table

If you need to update an existing row in your pivot table, you may use updateExistingPivot method. This method accepts the pivot record foreign key and an array of attributes to update:

```
$team->members()->updateExistingPivot($memberId, ['status' => 0]);
```

[source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships)

Regards

Comment: This method can update 'status' field, but only when the member are inside the table. If I change to other member, it will do nothing because the record is not exist, Sync can help to detach and attach, which is what I want, but I just cant find a solution to update extra column when using sync